# Could there be a romantic relationship between an ancient immortal and young mortal without a power imbalance?

Tags: immortality, relationships, dating, power

Romantic relationships with serious age-gaps are controversial in real life. It is often seen as the older person is engaging in predatory behavior since they are generally both wiser and richer than their younger partner. It can also be seen as gross since really old people generally aren't physically attractive.

In real life though, these age gaps are on the span of a few decades like a 20 year age gap or a 30 year age gap. In fiction, there are immortal beings who have been alive for centuries or even millennia. Even a 40 year age gap is small potatoes compared to a person born in Ancient Rome dating a person born in the 1990s. Could an immortal being like in the *Highlander* franchise have a normal relationship with a mortal person born recently? The physical age of the older person isn't apparent thanks to their immortality but the predatory behavior criticism about the older person being wiser and probably richer than the younger person is even more amplified. In addition, there is a new criticism that the older person is just using the younger person for fun since the couple can't grow old together; once the younger person seriously ages, the older person can just easily move onto somebody else like they've been probably doing for a very long time.

Comment: Betteridge's law of headlines applies here.

Comment: VTC Too Story-Based. Whether or not there is a relationship is, at best, an off-topic choice of your characters and, at worst, an off-topic choice of yours, the storybuilder. Relationships may be affected by the rules of your world (pheromones, chemical interactions in the brain, consequences of a culture or society we helped you design), but an actual relationship is 100% story-based.

Comment: Imho not really answerable because this is an [Ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics) question. We humans do not have any ethics governing this type of relationship and can only project our existing standards and knowledge into the unknown.

Comment: The answer to “Could there be a romantic relationship between…” is yes. A feather duster and a candelabra? Yes. A dog and a cat? Yes. This is fiction, and anything can happen in your story. That’s not a problem in your story. What is the problem in your world? This is about that.

Comment: @VogonPoet - if you are thinking about that candelabra from Beauty and the Beast I see where you are going with that.  He was smooth like butter for sure.    Was there a feather duster?  There should have been.  Maybe in the sequel.

Comment: @Willk How could you miss [that part?](https://youtu.be/HVeR2VHHAEc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is such a relationship *possible*? Yes. Is such a relationship *likely*? No. Should such a relationship happen? Beyond the scope of this site to answer.

Let me break it down. No two human beings are inherently equal at all. It the eyes of the law, perhaps, but not from a practical standpoint of intelligence, knowledge, experience, physical prowess, etc. Yet, relationships still happen anyway, because relationships can happen in spite of differences between the two parties. Let us perform a *gedankenexperiment* - suppose this immortal was stricken with a bout of amnesia and didn't know they were an immortal and forgot about all their accumulated knowledge, power, experience, etc. Seemingly, this would enable a healthy relationship.

Now, suppose the immortal didn't get amnesia, but behaved exactly like they had. It would seem that this is *possible*, so thus a relationship could work.

Likely? No. Not a chance. The divide between the two is staggering, and the mortal component of the relationship would have to struggle with the knowledge of being in a relationship with an immortal. There are dozens of fictional works which address these kinds of details, by the way, but that's a story building problem, so I won't go into further detail.

Morality, by the way, is much the same - not a world building problem, so I'm not going to discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

## Depends on the Nature of Immortality

How does this immortality work and how does an individual immortal's maturity, wealth, and abilities evolve over time?

In theory, people gain more knowledge, money, fame, etc. as time goes on. *MAYBE* this isn't the case. *Maybe* knowledge, money, fame, and stuff associated with age stop appreciably accruing over time. *Maybe* the immortal is locked into the maturity and abilities of the average 20 year old from New Zealand, along with an attitude of not bothering with money.

Imagine immortal capabilities not so much as infinite growth curves, but as having limits. Limits that mortals can also reasonably achieve. This results in immortals who can become masters of a few fields, but slowly shift their expertise and capabilities over time. Let's call this *shifting immortality,* and it opens the door for a romance of equals between immortal and mortal souls. Yes, the mortal will grow old and eventually die, but there could be a window when the two are equals in power.

## Are There Equals?

This is a bit of a frame change. Equality in power is a very subjective thing, IMHO. The inherent differences between life experience, genes, and genders mean that there are always situations where one partner excels and "has the power." Humans are just too complicated (and are subject to things like culture) to produce two exactly powerful individuals. Every romance has power imbalances!

Don't worry about power imbalances! Address the bigger issues. Worry about why your teenage protagonist has a thing for sparkly dead guys!

## TL; DR Shifting Immortality Gives Equal Footing

If immortals hit some limits which a mortal can also hit, by whatever metrics you use to guage power, then a mortal and an immortal could reasonably romance each other as equals. This is not stable, as a mortal will age, but you are looking for the odds of a romance, not a life-long relationship.

Answer (score 0):

### At no point in history has it been more possible for this to happen

Take a master blacksmith, this blacksmith has been smithing for two thousand years. They are obviously better than all other black smiths and have more power. The materials and tools may have changed slightly, but it is still blacksmithing.

Take a master horse handler. They have been tending to horses for two thousand years. They may have gotten better equipment or dealt with different breeds, but ultimately it is still horse handling.

Now take a computer programmer born in the year 1950. That person is possibly the oldest C programmer. Anyone older can’t have more experience because the person born in 1950 started learning the language immediately after it was invented. Computer science and many other fields such as nuclear engineering, and computer aided jobs are only several decades old.

However, remember how you had to help you grandparents learn how to use a computer? Well unless these immortals are going out of their way to “stay hip” then they might be centuries behind on certain technologies.

Now remember than computer programmer is a real job but blacksmiths have been mostly replaced in industry and horses have been in the decline since the 20th century.

A young talented start up computer programmer in a Tesla will put Dracula on a horse to shame any day of the week.